# Mongodb driver C# Index not used

Tags: c#, mongodb, índices

In MongoDB:

```
db.estr.createIndex({_id:1, Atualizar:-1});
```

In C#

```
var a = await db.dados.Distinct(x=>x.codigo).toListAsync();
var b = await db.estr.find(x=>!a.contains(x._id) && x.Atualizar).toListAsync();
```

Index Stats

```
{
    "name" : "_id_1_Atualizar_-1",
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1.0,
        "Atualizar" : -1.0
    },
    "host" : "OMNIIS2012HOM:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0), <----- not utilizade
        "since" : ISODate("2020-03-24T11:00:25.011-03:00")
    }
}
```

x.Atualizar é boolean

Answer (score 0):

Recebi a resposta que resolveu [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838679/mongodb-drive-c-sharp-index-not-used)

Como o _id esta negado ele faz scan, então o ideal é criar o índice Atualizar/_id

```
db.estr.createIndex({Atualizar:-1, _id:1})
```

Dessa maneira ele busca por Atualizar e faz scan somente nos que preencherem essa condição, ficando muito mais rápido do que fazendo primeiramente por _id.